# DLL errors Windows Server 2016 with KB4537764 and Docker 18.03

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2016, windows-update

The Windows KB4537764 from 2020-02-11 on Windows Server 2016 seems to break at least Docker 18.03 so that none of the installed programs in a contain work.

We have eg. `svn` and `msbuild` installed and while working perfectly after the KB is removed they only return to the command line with the KB.

Are there any known mitigation except removing the KB?

Comment: Agree, we had to roll back the patch to fix all our build servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Microsoft is aware of the issue and has released an updated Docker image to correct the issue.  See the link below for more information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t